# Greyhound arrival points in NYC

Tags: new-york-city, greyhound

Does anyone know where the Greyhound bus from Washington, DC, to New York City stops at its destination? It's not clear from the web site.

Comment: Which specific bus do you need to know about?

Comment: Greyhound buses on this route stop at Port Authority.

Comment: @MichaelHampton the last time I looked, a few years ago, there were a few exceptions.

Comment: @phoog OK, let's say this: The web site would state explicitly if the route terminated somewhere other than Port Authority (e.g. "New York Wall St"). But during booking it only says "New York" for routes that do terminate at Port Authority.

Comment: @MichaelHampton that is a much more thorough way of putting it. It's somewhat confusing of Greyhound not to be more specific about "New York Port Authority," but there's not much to be done about that, I suppose.

Comment: Whilst in Port Authority, be sure to leave a few moments to check out the totally fabulous "42nd Street Ballroom" sculpture.  Highly recommended!

Answer (score 8):

Most but not all use the Port Authority Bus Terminal at 42nd St/8th Ave. At least at one time some of their discount Bolt Bus runs were on the main website but arrived elsewhere.